# restricting vertical scrolling to individual divs not the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have 98 separate divs aligned left to right on a web page, each one able to scroll individually from the others. They are all different sizes due to the images they contain, but all exceed the height of web browser. I would like to be able to scroll from the top of one div to the bottom without triggering the entire page to scroll downwards.

In other words, I want to make sure that ONLY the divs scroll and the browser window remains in the same position. I have found a lot of suggestions to questions similar to this saying to use `overflow:hidden`, but that command does not override scrolling when the divs exceed the browser window size.

The basic structure of my code is as follows:

```
<div class="container" id="one"><img src="strips/1.jpg" /></div>
```

```
#one {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 7296px;
    width: 172px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
     float:left;
}
```

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#one').html());
});
```

I have attached a JSFiddle link with my full code (it's long but highly repetitive) and a more detailed description of the project I'm working on. Hopefully this provides you with enough information.

http://jsfiddle.net/1uma0074/

Answer (score 0):

pls clear you want to scroll body inner content or individual divs. if body inner content then 
it will solve the problem if you want to scroll the content not the window
extend your cod with include the following.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    window_h = $(window).height();
 $('html').height(window_h);
 $('body').height(window_h);

 window_w = $(window).width();
 $('html').width(window_w);
 $('body').width(window_w);

});
```

```css
html{ overflow: hidden;}
body { overflow: scroll;}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put each div named **one,two etc...** inside **individual container
   div**

   2. Add **height:100%** to *html{}* and *body{}*
   3. Remove **dot** before *body{}*
   4. Add **overflow-y: scroll** and **float:left** properties to **.container{}**
   5. Make *height:100%* for **#everything{}**

Check my code below and implement for all other 97 scrollers.

-Cheers!

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#one').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#two').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#three').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#four').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#five').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#six').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seven').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eight').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#nine').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#ten').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eleven').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twelve').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirteen').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourteen').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fifteen').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixteen').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventeen').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eighteen').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#nineteen').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twenty').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twentyone').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twentytwo').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twentythree').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twentyfour').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twentyfive').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twentysix').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twentyseven').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twentyeight').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#twentynine').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirty').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirtyone').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirtytwo').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirtythree').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirtyfour').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirtyfive').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirtysix').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirtyseven').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirtyeight').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#thirtynine').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourty').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourtyone').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourtytwo').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourtythree').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourtyfour').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourtyfive').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourtysix').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourtyseven').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourtyeight').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fourtynine').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fifty').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fiftyone').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fiftytwo').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fiftythree').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fiftyfour').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fiftyfive').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fiftysix').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fiftyseven').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fiftyeight').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#fiftynine').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixty').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixtyone').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixtytwo').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixtythree').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixtyfour').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixtyfive').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixtysix').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixtyseven').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixtyeight').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#sixtynine').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventy').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventyone').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventytwo').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventythree').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventyfour').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventyfive').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventysix').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventyseven').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventyeight').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#seventynine').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eighty').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eightyone').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eightytwo').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eightythree').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eightyfour').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eightyfive').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eightysix').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eightyseven').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eightyeight').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#eightynine').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#ninety').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#ninetyone').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#ninetytwo').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#ninetythree').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#ninetyfour').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#ninetyfive').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#ninetysix').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#ninetyseven').html());
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('body').append($('#ninetyeight').html());
});
```

```css
html{height:100%; }
body {
 overflow:hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x:scroll;
height:100%;    
}

.horizontalscroll {
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y:hidden;
}

.container {
 overflow-y:scroll;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    
}
 
#one {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 172px;
 border-width: 0px;
 border-style: 0;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
  float:left;
    height: 7296px;
    
}

#everything {
 width: 9918px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 height:100%;
 border-width: 0px;
 border-style: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="everything">
    <div class="container"><div id="one"><img src="strips/1.jpg" /></div></div>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you! @user2758326 I applied your code and now my page no longer scroll downward (yay!) but also no longer scrolls horizontally... what can I do to fix that? also to clarify, I want to be able to scroll each of the 98 divs individually while the window remains in the same position. I also want to be able to scroll horizontally to access all 98 divs. thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Welcome! @Rica. Can you please post the link for your site/jsfiddle. So that i can easily fix the problem.

Comment: through some trial and error I found that the problem was in the combination of height: 100% and overflow: hidden under the css html tag. however, if I remove either style, the page scrolls in both directions. I've also tried specifying overflow-y: hidden and overflow-x: scroll but that still let me scroll in both directions. I would still like to hold the horizontal position of the page constant while being able to scroll horizontally. Here's my code and a brief description of my project but be warned, it's very repetitive. Thanks for all your help! http://jsfiddle.net/1uma0074/18/

Comment: Here's a link to the rough draft of the site as well, so you can get an idea of what it actually looks like: http://www-scf.usc.edu/~gmaestas/wovenweb.html

Comment: on your website add a new div inside each container div and give them id like one,two,three... then remove id from container div.  paste this css then:
 
.container { overflow-x: hidden;}
body { overflow-x: scroll;  overflow-y: hidden;}
body, html,.container, .wrapper { height: 99%;}

Comment: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvishnu/1uma0074/26/) Here is jsfiddle.
remove height:auto form #everything{} and move divs named one, two... inside container. refer the full css styles and remove unwanted.